# Video lag issues on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I know similar questions exist but all I've seen are about older versions and/or the answers did not help.

As said in the title, I'm using Kubuntu 20.04(.2) LTS. My GPU is ADM. I was using the "bleeding edge" mesa drivers (PPA mesa oibaf), but I read that those can often break systems since they're not always stable. I was experiencing weird desktop issues that I thought could be from the drivers, so I switched to the stable release (kisak mesa PPA). I'm no longer having those desktop issues, but now I have ridiculous video lag. I have updated/upgraded and it's a PPA so they should be the current drivers. I'm not sure how to fix this. I considered changing to the drivers you download directly from the ADM website, but I read that only really helps if you need open-cl support? I also couldn't find a release of it compatible with my system - most recent is 20.04.1. I'd rather use the PPA drivers anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the kisak mesa PPA and falling back on the default open source drivers fixed my issues. I was worried I'd have to reinstall those drivers but simply deleting the PPA worked in my case since I never deleted the default drivers.